# Can't load datasets from linearmodel python package

Tags: python, pip, conda, linearmodels

I am trying to learn the linearmodels package for python.
I want to do this by practicing with the data sets, as can be seen [here](https://pypi.org/project/linearmodels/).
Example code:

```
import numpy as np
from linearmodels.iv import IV2SLS
from linearmodels.datasets import mroz
data = mroz.load()
```

But my code breaks when i run `data = mroz.load()`

error message:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\linearmodels\\datasets\\mroz\\mroz.csv.bz2'
```

I have pip version: 19.1.1

Conda can't find the package at all

and i have the latest version of linearmodels package: 4.13

The  folder specified in the error message i can find, i.e. `datasets\mroz` but not the csv.bz2 file.

The same holds for every other data set i try to open.

**Why am i not able to open the datasets?**

let me know if you need additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the package. If you download and unpack the source distribution you would find it lacks all `*.csv.bz2`.

I see two problems in the package. First, `MANIFEST.in` [lists](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/blob/0abbac53dc2512567efa41b457b29d86a260477e/MANIFEST.in#L5) `*.csv.bz`. It must be  `*.csv.bz2` or `*.csv.bz*`.

Second, they tried to [add the datasets in `setup.py`](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/blob/0abbac53dc2512567efa41b457b29d86a260477e/setup.py#L82) but also failed, not sure why. Perhaps the files must be declared as belonged to different subpackages, not to the main package.

Please report the bugs to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/bashtage/linearmodels/issues).